# Async/Await with Redux-thunk. Getting Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to use async await with redux-thunk middleware but I get the red screen with the error  Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. I suppose I'm not returning the right type of value. I press a button to link twitter user to an existing firebase account. That button reaches a function called toggleTwitterAuthState:

```
export const toggleTwitterAuthState =  (twitterIsCurrentlyLinked, contributorUserId) => {

  let actionName = "";


    if (twitterIsCurrentlyLinked) {
      console.log("Unlinking twitter");
      actionName = "TWITTER_UNLINK";
       unlinkTwitterAccount(contributorUserId);
    } else {
      console.log("Linking twitter");
      linkTwitterAccount(contributorUserId);
      actionName = "TWITTER_LINK";
    }



};
```

It calls the function linkTwitterAccount, I'm using the react-native-debugger put a breakpoint on the return async (dispatch) and it reaches there, but the code inside never get executed and I get that red screen with the error described above

```
linkTwitterAccount =  (contributorUserId) => {

       return async (dispatch)=>{

        console.log("about to link twitter user");
        RNTwitterSignIn.init(config.twitter.consumer_key, config.twitter.consumer_secret);
        dispatch(authOperationBegan());

        let linkToTwitterResult;
        let twitterTokensObject;
        let loginData;
        //get credentials

        try {
          loginData = await RNTwitterSignIn.logIn();
          console.log("Twitter login data", loginData);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("Error with twitter login result", error);
          dispatch(authOperationFailed(err));
        }

        //link to react native firebase

        try {

          const {
            authToken,
            authTokenSecret
          } = loginData;
          const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
          // create a new firebase credential with the token
          const twitterCredential = firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.credential(authToken, authTokenSecret);
          console.log(twitterCredential);

          // link to this account with credential
          const linkingResult = await user.linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(twitterCredential);
          console.log("Success Linking twitter", linkingResult);

          var currentUser = linkingResult.user;

          var displayName;
          var photoUrl;
          var email;
          var phoneNumber;
          var twitterUserId;

          currentUser.providerData.map(elem => {
            if (elem.providerId == "twitter.com") {

              displayName = elem.displayName;
              photoUrl = elem.photoURL;
              email = elem.email;
              phoneNumber = elem.phoneNumber;
              twitterUserId = elem.uid;

            }
          });


          twitterTokensObject = {
            "contributor_user_id": contributorUserId,
            "twitter_id": twitterUserId,
            "twitter_access_token": authToken,
            "twitter_access_token_secret": authTokenSecret,
            "display_name": displayName,
            "photo_url": photoUrl,
            "phone_number": phoneNumber,
            "email": email
          };


        } catch (err) {
          alert("Error linking asociando cuenta: " + err);
          dispatch(authOperationFailed(err));
        }

        //TODO: upsert twitter user data to DB

        dispatch(authOperationFinished());
       }
      }
```

My redux thunk configuration is like this, I learnt it from a udemy course where the guy uses a componse function https://www.udemy.com/react-native-the-practical-guide/ :

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import foundationsReducer from './reducers/foundations';
import sponsorsReducer from './reducers/sponsors';
import authReducer from './reducers/auth';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    foundations: foundationsReducer,
    sponsors: sponsorsReducer,
    auth:authReducer
});

let composeEnhancers = compose;

if (__DEV__) {
    composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
}

const configureStore = () => {
    return createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
};

export default configureStore;
```

I use this redux thunk configuration on my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App';
import configureStore from './src/store/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

const RNRedux = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('rnfundkers', () => RNRedux);
```

Just for you to know, redux thunk is working of for other actions, but this async await case is different in a way I'm not being able to see. Any idea of what could be wrong? And the function itself works if I get rid of the wrapper and the dispatches, it does what it have to do but since I needed those dispatches to update the spinner then this problem arose. Thanks!!

EDIT: Here are the actions:

```
export const authOperationBegan =  () => {
  return {
    type: AUTH_OPERATION_BEGAN
  };
}

export const authOperationFinished =  () => {
  return {
    type: AUTH_OPERATION_FINISHED
  };
}

export const authOperationFailed =  (err) => {
  return {
    type: AUTH_OPERATION_FAILED,
    error: err
  };
}
```

I have other functions that dispatch those same 3 actions and they work fine, for example this one:

```
export const tryAuth = (authData, authMode) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(authOperationBegan());

    const email = authData.email,
      password = authData.password;

    if (authMode === "signup") {

      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((user) => {


          // TODO: upsert user to our db
          dispatch(authOperationFinished());

        })
        .catch((error) => {
          const {
            code,
            message
          } = error;

          dispatch(authOperationFailed(err));

        });

    } else if (authMode == "login") {

      firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((data) => {

          dispatch(authOperationFinished());

        })
        .catch((error) => {
          const {
            code,
            message
          } = error;
          console.log("error", message);

          dispatch(authOperationFailed(err));

        });

    }

  };
};
```

Comment: what do the authOperation actions look like?

Comment: bspaka. I edited my post. I added the specification of the dispatched actions at the end of it. I also included an example of a function that dispatch those same 3 actions and works ok....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to dispatch your thunk

```
export const toggleTwitterAuthState =  (twitterIsCurrentlyLinked, contributorUserId) => dispatch => {
  let actionName = "";
  if (twitterIsCurrentlyLinked) {
    console.log("Unlinking twitter");
    actionName = "TWITTER_UNLINK";
    unlinkTwitterAccount(contributorUserId);
  } else {
    console.log("Linking twitter");
    dispatch(linkTwitterAccount(contributorUserId));
    actionName = "TWITTER_LINK";
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked wonders. The complete code would be your solution plus wrapping everything with a return (dispatch) so in that way that function will be available.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, in the rush to answer, the answer was incomplete, I've added more details.